# Writing a function that has two inputs

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, homework, abort

> 2. Write a function called DOTPRODUCT that has two inputs u and v,
>    assumed to be two non-empty lists of numbers of arbitrary length,
>    checks that the two lists are of equal length, prints an error message and
>    aborts if the two lengths are unequal, and computes the dot product of the two
>    lists if the lengths are equal.

Comment: see the tutorials [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) and [Putting Constraints On Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html)

Comment: I have been trying to look at that. New to programming and would like some hints

Comment: Is this a homwork assignment?